# Test if a function is threadsafe

Tags: python

I have a function like this

```
def party_id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    party_ids = []
    seen = set()
    while len(party_ids) < 2:
        party_id_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for x in range(5))
        party_id_dig = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(3))
        party_id = ''.join([party_id_str,party_id_dig])
        if party_id in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(party_id)
        party_ids.append(party_id)
    return party_ids
```

How would i know if the function is thread safe or not ?

Comment: A function that does not access or modify shared data is inherently "thread safe".

Comment: Thanks from your comment i discovered locking with threading